# fancyhdr messing up the document margins

Tags: longtable, fancyhdr, geometry

I wish to add header/footer to a document in landscape format. The document is basically a long table with few notes. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{My name}
\lhead{document title}
\cfoot{Page \thepage}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper, 
landscape,
top=2cm,
bottom=2cm,
left=3cm,
right=2cm,
includehead,includefoot,
heightrounded}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}p{4cm}p{1cm}p{2cm}p{4cm}}
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\Large\textbf{Name:} My Name} \\
College:& My college & & University: & My university
\end{longtable}
\vspace{3em}

\begin{large}
    Title of document
\end{large}
\end{center}

\begin{footnotesize}
some notes
\end{footnotesize} 
\end{document}
```

The output is all messed up:
[image: mess]

However, if I just remove the `fancyhdr` part from the code, there is no problem in the alignment of footer:

[image: what we want]

How can I align the `fancyhdr` with the document?

Comment: Load `fancyhdr` *after*  you load `geometry`.

Comment: also don't set `\textwidth` "by hand" if you are using `geometry` which will change it again later

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the tip! Where can I read more about these dependencies? Like which package should be loaded before others.

Comment: there are no general rules, but in this case it just follows some kind of natural logic that fancyhdr needs to know what page size it is making a header for, and geometry sets the page size....

Comment: OTOH, fancyhdr has a nasty habit of changing the geometry after the first page.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in your code you have some issues:

1. You are using definitions you do not need if you use package `geometry`:

   ```
   %\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm} % <=======================================
   %\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
   %\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}
   ```
2. The order of calling packages `geometry` and `fancyhdr` is important! You need to call `geometry` first to define all margins. This correct defined margins can then be used by `fancyhdr` to insert the needed header and footers ...

   ```
   \usepackage{geometry} % <===============================================
   \geometry{%
     letterpaper, 
     landscape,
     top=2cm,
     bottom=2cm,
     left=3cm,
     right=2cm,
     includehead,includefoot,
     heightrounded
   }

   \usepackage{fancyhdr} % <===============================================
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   \fancyhf{}
   \rhead{My name}
   \lhead{document title}
   \cfoot{Page \thepage}
   ```
3. `fancyhdr` creates on the first page the header and footer and test if the available space for header and footer is enough or not. In your case you get the warning (see your log file):

   ```
   Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
   Make it at least 13.59999pt.
   ```

   So you need to add the line

   ```
   \setlength{\headheight}{14pt} % <=======================================
   ```

   to your preamble ...

Please see the following complete and compilable mwe

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm} % <=======================================
%\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}

\usepackage{geometry} % <===============================================
\geometry{%
  letterpaper, 
  landscape,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  left=3cm,
  right=2cm,
  includehead,includefoot,
  heightrounded
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % <===============================================
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{My name}
\lhead{document title}
\cfoot{Page \thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt} % <=======================================

\setlength\parindent{0pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}p{4cm}p{1cm}p{2cm}p{4cm}}
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\Large\textbf{Name:} My Name} \\
College:& My college & & University: & My university
\end{longtable}
\vspace{3em}

\begin{large}
    Title of document
\end{large}
\end{center}

\begin{footnotesize}
some notes
\end{footnotesize} 

\clearpage
\begin{footnotesize}
some notes
\end{footnotesize} 
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image]